# CSS - Resolve scroll bar being covered by tiled auto size images

Tags: css, image, tile

I found some great help on this site that helped me tile an image on either side of my fixed header. One issue I am having is the scroll bar on the right is being covered by the tiled image and becoming inaccessible. I am sure it is something simple but I am at a loss at the moment. You can view an example here: http://www.jzandecki.com/example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to rebuild your header from scratch. First of all create a div (this will be your header container), name it with id let's say "header". Add as a background your tiled black image. The position of that div should be FIXED and not ABSOLUTE.

```
position: fixed;
background: url("../images/example_top.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
height: 178px;
width: 100%;
```

In your header div add another div having for width size the width of your power plant image. Set the css of this div to margin: auto (to center it in the screen).

```
margin: auto;
```

This should do the job.
If this works you should have the same view you had before but your scroll bar will be on top of your header and not hidden.

Edit:

By the way I saw your body is 900 px and sticks on the left of the screen. I recommend you to have the following attribute for your body:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

The body should occupy the whole page.
If you want a 900 px wrapper block for your content add a div AFTER your header div (described above). This new div should have the following css attributes:

```
width: 900px;
margin: auto; //this centers your div in the middle of your screen
//Other styles that have nothing to do with positioning
```

Good luck.

Comment: Alex, I have tried your suggestions but I am still having the same issue. You can check out my work at http://www.jzandecki.com/example/example2.html to make sure i did you suggestion correctly.

Comment: In your body's css remove the overflow: auto; attribute, this will fix the problem. 
I suggest you to add the following instead:
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll; 
You will always have the right bar with this case (even if the page doesn't need scrolling, in firefox for example) but it's better for user experience (if the page dynamically grows as the user visits the website).

Comment: Alex, removing "overflow: auto;" from the body's css did the trick and gave me the result I was looking for! When add "overflow-x: hidden;" and "overflow-y: scroll;" the problem returns so I left them out. You can check my desired result at http://www.jzandecki.com/example/example3.html . Thanks for your help!

Comment: Alright it's great it's working now! Once you feel like your problem is fixed check my first post (or the one before that solved the actual problem) so that other people don't answer to a problem that has been solved. Good luck for the following.